# Possible index corruption detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration, dbcc

I received an alert "Possible index corruption detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB"
I checked the error logs and they are:
"
Possible index corruption detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB
Error:9100, Severity: 23, State: 2
"

My question would be how will I determine which database to run DBCC on? I couldn't find a message pointing to which db raised this alert.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Try to look in the SQL Server LOG-folder.
Your answer could be in a dump log-file.
If you still have a default trace from the time of the incident, you could try to look in the trace-files (*.trc) in the LOG-folder. Hint - Secure the trc-files by copying them to another folder before reading.
I hope you find your root-cause.

/niels

Comment: Man it was helpful but didn't solve :( Tried to bump your rep up but didn't allow because I didn't have enough reps. Thank you.